# Is HCl(l) acidic?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, water

If in a reaction mixture HCl is given in liquid phase, will it behave as an acid ?

I know that an aqueous solution of HCl is acidic but am confused about the liquid phase.

Answer (score 5):

It would act as an acid if there were even slightly basic atoms available to protonate. Pure liquid HCl probably would probably have a pretty high $\text{p} (\ce{H2Cl^+})$, though, due to the very low basicity of the chloride ion. In other words, it would have a very low autoionization constant, similar or less than that of $\ce{H2SO4}$ (which has a higher pKa pure than it does in water), based on their similar aqueous pKa values.

I say "less than" because stabilizing ions would be harder due to the smaller size and higher concentration of charge of the  $\ce{H2Cl^+}$ and $\ce{Cl^-}$ ions relative to the more diffuse $\ce{H3SO4^+}$ and $\ce{HSO4^-}$ ions.

Comment: In fact, autoionization constant of $\ce{H2SO4}$ is not that low; it is way higher than that of water. Not sure about liquid $\ce{HCl}$, though.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Indeed, $\ce{H2SO4}$ is has a much higher autoionization constant than water, but as far as mineral acids go, I think it's fairly low. Interestingly, sulfuric acid autoionizes to water and hydrogen pyrosulfate. It's autoionization constant is $7x10^-5$. Nitric acid, however, has an autoionization constant of $2x10^-2$. I haven't yet found one for $\ce{HCl}$, and I'm still looking, but I believe it would be much less than either of these.