# Does hydrogen chloride gas react with metals?

Tags: acid-base

I searched and couldn't find any reactions with $\ce{HCl (g)}$ as a reactant, only with the acid in the aqueous phase ($\ce{HCl (aq)}$). Do metals react with $\ce{HCl}$ gas to form hydrogen?

Comment: Umm... which metals -- Au? Cs? At what temperature -- 4.3 K? 1,273 K?

Comment: Any. My question is does it react or not in gaseous state.

Comment: Gaseous $\ce{HCl}$ do not react as an acid. For example, it does not react with calcium carbonate.

Comment: @Maurice, the OP was asking about reaction with metal, not acid/base reaction. However, it's too broadly worded to answer. Likely, it *would* react with Cs at 2,000 K, though I have no wish to test that. AS to whether H2 would be released, or form CsH, that's another question.

Comment: HCl gas would certainly react with any adsorbed water on the surface, and I'd guess that no surface exposed to the atmosphere is absolutely dry.

Comment: Worse yet, gaseous HCl will _condense water_ from the atmosphere, and then...

Answer (score 1):

I have found no definitive evidence for a reaction of hydrogen chloride gas with metals, but it can react with bases that do not require a redox reaction. [This answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/135174/17175), citing References [1-3], discusses the anhydrous reaction between hydrogen chloride and ammonia. Combination of single molecules of $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{NH3}$ gives a hydrogen-bonded $\ce{NH4Cl}$ monomer rather than an ionic one; the proton is not fully transferred. The fully proton-transferred, ionic product is formed when this monomer is polymerized by further reaction.

Hartman et al. [[4]](https://doi.org/10.1021/ie503480k) describe the reaction of hydrogen chloride with solid sodium carbonate at 500°C, forming the familiar products seen in the aqueous reaction (sodium chloride, carbon dioxide, water). In this case the formation of water implies that the hydrogen chloride does not remain dry. Presumably it forms hydrogen-bonded monomers or oligomers with the water, similar to the ammonium chloride monomer described above. See also Ref. [3].

**References**

1. Robert A. Cazar, Alan J. Jamka, and Fu-Ming Tao (1998). "Ab Initio Investigation of Proton Transfer in Ammonia−Hydrogen Chloride and the Effect of Water Molecules in the Gas Phase", J. Phys. Chem. A., 102, 26, 5117–5123.
2. Richard J. Countess and Julian Heicklen (1973). "Kinetics of particle growth. II. Kinetics of the reaction of ammonia with hydrogen chloride and the growth of pariculate ammonium chloride", *J. Phys. Chem.* ,77, 4, 444–447.
3. Galina M. Chaban, R. Benny Gerber, and Kenneth C. Janda (2001). "Transition from Hydrogen Bonding to Ionization in (HCl)n(NH3)n and (HCl)n(H2O)n Clusters:  Consequences for Anharmonic Vibrational Spectroscopy", *J. Phys. Chem. A*, 105, 36, 8323–8332.
4. Miloslav Hartman, Karel Svoboda, Michael Pohořelý, Michal Šyc, Siarhei Skoblia, and Po-Chuang Chen (2014).
   "Reaction of Hydrogen Chloride Gas with Sodium Carbonate and Its Deep Removal in a Fixed-Bed Reactor".
   *Ind. Eng. Chem. Res.* , 53, 49, 19145–19158.
   https://doi.org/10.1021/ie503480k